# Android textview id by string

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, resource-id

I have a textview whose id is asd1
If I save asd1 in a string how can I use that string to R.id.(id from string)
Meaning how can I use the string to get resource id in a fragment

Comment: The second snippet in [this answer on the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476470) has exactly what you're looking for. You would need to call `getPackageName()` on `getActivity()`/`getContext()` instead, though.

Comment: Be warned that there is most likely a better solution to your original problem than what you are trying to do here.