# Get drawable image by its name

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I have a model and it has a specific country flag:

```
public int getCountryFlag() {
    return countryFlag;
}

public void setCountryFlag(int countryFlag) {
    this.countryFlag = countryFlag;
}
```

I am getting Data from an API. The API has a value country code and this could be like: `"country":"de","created_at":"2018-08-08 09:17:43","updated_at":"2018-08-08 09:17:43"`

I have the flags named as the country code:

```
de
se
us
....
```

How can I get the exact resourceID of the image to relate it to the model?
I am using RecyclerView.

I tried something like:

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(object.getString("country"), "drawable",  getPackageName());
model.setCountryFlag(R.drawable.sy);
```

Though that didn't work!

Comment: what is this ? `model.setCountryFlag(R.drawable.sy);`.

Comment: so are you saying that your drawable resource has the same name as that returned by the api? and your question is how to use that to access the drawable file?

Comment: Hey Jacob, that is exactly what I am saying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure about the format of the `api` string then do the following:

```
String country = api.trim().split(",")[0].split(":")[1].replaceAll("\"", "");
```

or

```
String country = api.trim().substring(11, 13);
```

and then:

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(country, "drawable",  getPackageName());
model.setCountryFlag(resID);
```

Comment: I am sure about the format of the API and I get the value of 0 always. So it's an exception error

Comment: @Mike So if you use `String country = api.substring(11, 13);` do you get the 2 letters for the country?

Comment: Oh damn! This is working actually. I had forgotten to rename the file. I simply didn't have it correct in the folder. Thanks man :))

Comment: Fine___________

Answer (score 0):

You can get flag by Resource Id name

```
int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("de", "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```

you can also check 
[How to get a resource id with a known resource name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/how-to-get-a-resource-id-with-a-known-resource-name)