# How to get specific menu item icon resource id?

Tags: android, menu, icons, drawable

Menu is defined like this:

```
<item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="@string/menu_slideshow"
            app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"/>
```

I need to know `android:icon` value as provided in xml. There is a method `getIcon()` but it returns `Drawabe` object. How to get resource id as `int`?

[edit] Not a duplicate, solution proposed as possible answer is unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there is no way to get resource ID of a already retrieved resource. But if it helps, you can get its ID by its name. You can read how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3476430/2940733)