# Expand string from variable name

Tags: java, android

I have a bunch of strings in `strings.xml`, named eg a1, a2, a3, a4:

```
<string name="a1">url1</string>
<string name="a2">url2</string>
<string name="a3">url3</string>
<string name="a4">url4</string>
```

I've setup a randomiser to create a random number, eg between 1 and 4

I've then created a variable to add the letter 'a' to the random number eg `a3`

```
String url = "a" + (+randint);
```

This prints 'a3' successfully:

```
System.out.println((url));
```

I'm now trying to display the contents of the '`a3`' string in textview or even just `System.out.((url))` but can't figure out how to expand the variable as `url3`. At best I can only pull out 'a3'. Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to have a correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/how-to-get-a-resource-id-with-a-known-resource-name

Comment: `I've setup a randomiser to create a random number, eg between 1 and 4` why aren't you just using this random value to pull one of the url values from an array ? you're saying that you have `a3` and you want to display `url3` ?