# Insert Image using variable name in Kotlin

Tags: android, list, android-studio, for-loop, imageview

I currently am working on an app that has a list of characters and images associated with each of them.

I want to insert images for all the characters using a for loop without actually hardcoding their image names:

Example:

```
var agentsList = listOf(
        "Astra",
        "Breach",
        "Brimstone",
        "Chamber",
        "Cypher",
        "Jett",
        "KAY/O",
        "Killjoy",
        "Neon",
        "Omen",
        "Phoenix",
        "Raze",
        "Reyna",
        "Sage",
        "Skye",
        "Sova",
        "Viper",
        "Yoru"
    )
for (agent in agentsList) {
    dataList.add(DataModel(agent, R.drawable.agent)
}
```

Here , R.drawable.agent is where I want to insert the images , but i want the for loop to do it for me using the string resource in agentsList.

I have saved the image using the same strings as the characters in agentsList, so that won't be an issue.

Comment: Use "getResources().getIdentifier".  Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57304564/2173056

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string name to get drawable resource identifier:

```
for (agent in agentsList) {
    val resources: Resources = context.resources
    val resourceId: Int = resources.getIdentifier(agent, "drawable", context.packageName)
    dataList.add(DataModel(agent, resourceId)
}
```