# Pull String Array Dynamically with name

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, dynamic

I want to use an intent string extra to dynamically determine what String array in an XML file to use.
Java code:

```
 Intent myIntent = getIntent();
 String stringID = myIntent.getStringExtra("stringID");//pull string id

 String[] allStrings = getResources().getStringArray(stringID);
```

The XML:

```
<string-array name="set1">
    <item>item1</item>
    <item>item2</item>
    <item>item3</item>
</string-array>
```

The last line in the java code doesn't work because it wants something like r.array.set1, but I want to choose this dynamically instead. How can I accomplish this? Would it be easier to use the ID of the string array somehow?

Comment: It sounds like you want to look up a resource by its name dynamically, rather than hard-coding to the resource identifier? If so, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476470/3032

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually *r.array.set1* is a reference to an Integer. So you should pass it as an Integer, not a String. So:

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent();
int intID = myIntent.getIntExtra("stringID", r.array.set1);//The second parameter is the default value if nothing is specified

String[] allStrings = getResources().getStringArray(intID);
```

And in the other activity pass it as an Integer:

```
intent.putExtra("stringID", r.array.set1);
```

Comment: I had to use some more code in the calling activity to pull the resource ID properly, but this works far better than what I was initially trying to do. Thanks.