# Map Strings to Android Drawable Resource ID, without affecting resource shrinking

Tags: android, proguard, android-resources, aapt, android-r8

My Android library contains ~1300 drawables.  For server driven UI, applications need to efficiently retrieve each drawable using a backend specified string ID (assume it's the resource name for simplicity).  There's separate logic for retrieving images from fallback URLs, the goal here is return an image instantly if we have it, rather than look it up.  I can easily generate and include a kotlin source mapping in the library, e.g.

```
@DrawableRes fun toImageId(name:String):Int {
    return when(name) {
        "image_one"  -> R.drawable.image_one
        "image_two"  -> R.drawable.image_two
        ...
        "image_thirteen_hundred" -> R.drawable.image_thirteen_hundred
    }
```

However I *don't* want to this mapping to prevent R8/Proguard from shrinking images that aren't used anywhere else. Otherwise several apps will unacceptably increase in size.  As far as I can tell there isn't a way to exclude a source file from consideration of what resources are used. Many posts, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/how-to-get-a-resource-id-with-a-known-resource-name), recommend retrieving the asset directly through the resource name i.e.

```
resources.getIdentifier(resIdName, "drawable", packageName)
```

which does evade detection by resource shrinking, but is extremely slow.  A unit test retrieving a single resource takes about 2 seconds. A test retrieving all the IDs takes almost 4 seconds.

Is there another viable approach to this problem?

**EDIT**: @CommonsWare is correctly points out that the actual in-app performance of getIdentifier() is orders of magnitude better than in unit tests. Effectively making it a non-issue.

Comment: "However I don't want to this mapping to prevent R8/Proguard from shrinking images that aren't used anywhere else" -- that would seem like it would break the server-driven UI. Suppose the app using your library references zero of your resources, using everything through the server-driven UI. What you want is for all of the resources to be removed by shrinking, and the server-driven UI then fails when it tries to reference any of the drawables. "but is extremely slow" -- if that's for resolving all 1300 at once, lazy resolve them, caching the results.

Comment: Good call out. I have separate logic for retrieving missing (or shrunk) drawable from fallback URLs, so the goal here is just to be able to quickly retrieve whichever assets *are* used (or manually kept) by each application.

The 2-3 seconds was for retrieving a single resource id, but two was about the same. I agree that caching is the obvious mitigation if there aren't other options, in which case I'll update with less bare-bones benchmarking.

Comment: I'd reconsider having a library with 1300 drawable resources.  That's a huge and inefficient memory footprint.  You're better off downloading the images as you actually need them.  Especially if you have fallback download logic anyway-  just use a disk cache.

Comment: "The 2-3 seconds was for retrieving a single resource id" -- that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Maybe inlining the map function will do the trick?

Comment: @CommonsWare I updated the wording, a unit test takes 2 second longer to complete with 1 lookup and 4 seconds longer  to look up everything. Please LMK if there's a better way to benchmark, I didn't dig too deep since multiple posts comment on how slow it is.

Comment: @ltp interesting, I'd worry a bit since you're not supposed to inline large methods for performance.  It would be interesting to know if that would trick the shrinker though.

Comment: @Tbadams: A unit test isn't using actual Android. An instrumented test would. Personally, I would use actual app code. Last I checked -- which admittedly was probably a decade ago -- it was about a millisecond for `getIdentifier()` to return, on then-current Android hardware. That's relatively expensive for something that does no I/O, but it's way less than what you are reporting. Resources have gotten more complicated, so I can't completely rule out a three-orders-of-magnitude increase in time.

Comment: @Tbadams, if name is known at compile time, R8 will inline the resource id directly at call site and will get rid of the map function and unused/unreferenced drawables.