# Link XML to Resources

Tags: android, xml, uiimageview

I have an XML file:

```
<building>
    <room IMAGE="R.raw.room" />
</building>
```

but I don't know how to link the value of IMAGE to my main program... When I do this:

```
[... parsing xml file and detect room ...]
ImageView image = findViewByID(xml.getAttributeValue(0));
```

it don't works.. Cause it returns me a String and not a int. How can I link this XML file to my resources?

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using getResources().getIdentifier()?

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042961/how-can-i-get-the-resource-id-of-an-image-if-i-know-its-name)

Answer (score 0):

`R.raw.room` is an identifier generated by compiler for a file. You cannot load from XML. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Well.. Maybe I didn't explain my problem very well. I have the name of the resource "R.raw.room" in a String, and I want to find the ID of this "R.raw.room"

Comment: You didn't explain your problem at all. Since R.raw.room is a composite identifier, I doubt you can parse a string to get it. So, why do you need such an approach?