# Find view by name

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to find a view by its name rather than its id.

```
findViewById(R.id.someView);
```

but I would like to do something like this:

```
findViewByName("someView");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the resource id of an image if I know its name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042961/how-do-i-get-the-resource-id-of-an-image-if-i-know-its-name)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

you have to find views by identifier when dealing with xml, but you can look up the identifier by using [getIdentifier(String name, ...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) which is useful if you have your layouts numbered for example. Just be aware that such a lookup is relatively expensive.

**to complete the answer**

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "id", context.getPackageName());
View view = findViewById(id);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, we can find any static resources by name too.

```
 int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "id", context.getPackageName());
View view;
if(id != 0) {
  view = findViewById(id);
}
```

getResources().identifier will return 0 always if resource not found or name doesn't match.

Comment: And how is this different from @MrJre answer? ... don't clutter the site with duplicates.