# How to get an item in string array and put it on different TextView

Tags: java, android

Please help I am new to java and android.

Here is the example of the string array resource

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
   <string-array name="dance_steps">
       <item>Step1</item>
       <item>Step2</item>
       <item>Step3</item>
       <item>Step4</item>
   </string-array>
</resources>
```

How can I get the Strings and put it on different `TextView` in the java code?

```
 TextView step1, step2, step3, step4;
 step1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
 step2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
 step3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview3);
 step4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview4);

 Resources res = getResources();
 String[] steps = res.getStringArray(R.array.dance_steps);

 step1.setText(item number 1 in String Array);
 step2.setText(item number 2 in String Array);
 step3.setText(item number 3 in String Array);
 step4.setText(item number 4 in String Array);
```

Thankyou.

Comment: step1.setText(steps[0]) and steps[1] so on

Comment: If you want to do it automatically just find views id by name (join for loop index number with name) see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6831562/2815288)

Comment: thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to pass the string array. Here is more efficient code -

```
TextView step[] = new TextView[4];
step[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
step[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
step[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview3);
step[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview4);

Resources res = getResources();
String[] steps = res.getStringArray(R.array.dance_steps);

for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){
    step[i].setText(steps[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
step1.setText(steps[0]);
step2.setText(steps[1]);
step3.setText(steps[2]);
step4.setText(steps[3]);
```

You should go through Java basics

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView step[] = new TextView[4];
step[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
step[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
step[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview3);
step[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview4);

Resources res = getResources();
String[] steps = res.getStringArray(R.array.dance_steps);

for(int i = 0 ; i < steps.length ; i++){
    step[i].setText(steps[i]);
}
```