# How to use a String as Image-Name at runtime

Tags: android, image

I have many Images and I would like to write a short-code
I just want to change the image name at the runtime and the code should insert the Picture in the correct image
I Try like that :

```
    img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_1);
    img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_2);
    img3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_3);
    img4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_4); }

public void Load_IN_img1(View view) {
    image_x="img1"; 
  Picasso.with(Main.this).load("http://blabla.comimage1.png").into(image_x);  


public void Load_IN_img1(View view) {
    image_x="img2"; 
 Picasso.with(Main.this).load("http://blabla.comimage1.png").into(image_x);
```

that means, if i change the string image_x to "img4" so the code should insert the Picture in the wanted image, into img4.

How can I find the image-name at runtime ?

Answer (score 1):

thanks People, after long searching in google, i found the solution here in forum too :
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831506/find-view-by-name)

```
public void Load_IN_img1(View view) {    
 String  image_x="imageView1";// variable 
  int id = getResources().getIdentifier(image_x, "id",   
  this.getPackageName()); 
  ImageView img = findViewById(id);
 Picasso.with(Main.this).load("http://blabla.comimage1.png").into(image_x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the perfect way is using view id. 
Ex: 
**relatedViewId** = public static final int value which is **defined in R.java**

```
public void loadImage(View view) {
    image_x = (ImageView) findViewById(relatedViewId);
    Picasso.with(Main.this)
    .load("http://blabla.comimage1.png")
    .into(image_x);
}
```

Additionally, you can use any other way to solve this problem like reflection, String.equals etc.. However, **relatedViewId** is **more performance** than **others**.

Comment: but i have to change the String from time to time. . where can I put my String (imageView-name) in your code ?

Comment: **relatedViewId** is the parameter of the function.
`public void loadImage(int relatedViewId) {
    ImageView relatedView = (ImageView) findViewById(relatedViewId);
    Picasso.with(Main.this)
    .load("http://blabla.comimage1.png")
    .into(relatedView);
}`