# FindViewByID with a variable

Tags: java, android, android-cardview

I have a CardView in AndroidStudio with different ID's for each card. To search the different ID's i have made this:

```
for (int f = 0; f < mainGrid.getChildCount(); f++) {
    if (f == count) {
        int index = f;
        String id = "food"+index;

        foodName =  findViewById(R.id.id);
        foodName.getText();
    }
}
```

But at `foodName =  findViewById(R.id.id);` says that "Cannot resolve symbol id"

There's any other way to do it?

Comment: @Ivar I see you don't program Android apps?

Comment: @ZUNJAE Yes, I removed the comment when I noticed it. Drew my conclusion a bit too fast.

Answer (score 2):

No matter how many times you loop, if you do not have a view named `id` in your layout, you will get the error you are getting.

You cannot use a variable called `id` and then tag it onto `R.id.id` (which resolves as a numeric id value)

If you want to find a view when you know only its name, see this:

[Find view by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831506/find-view-by-name)