# Textview declaration using a variable String

Tags: android

Is it possible declare many diferent TextView. Like tv_concept1, tv_concept2, tv_concept3... and so on.
 Using a variable string? If the string is "1" it would declare tv_concept1. So it will change the tv_concept1 text to Hi. But if the variable is it 2 then other TextView will do it.

````
    String textview = "tv_concept" + value;
    TextView textview = findViewById(R.id.textview);
    textview.setText("Hi");```
````

Comment: Can this link help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831506/find-view-by-name

Comment: yeeah!THANKS, this worked perfectly tilll the moment of setText. There is not the method for the VIEW. any idea how I could do?

Comment: Which is the View method?
I think you can set a string to TextView with the following code.

`int value = 1;
String textview = "tv_concept" + value;

int id = getResources().getIdentifier(textview, "id", getPackageName());
TextView view = findViewById(id);
view.setText("Hi");`

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I did the declaration  without the ( Textview) only     view = findViewById(id);  This works reaaly fine now!! Doubt solved!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array of your object.