# How to get Android String Array if i have Array name in another String

Tags: android, string, android-resources, arrays

I have a problem, a technical one. I have a list view, when I click an item I get content at that specific position and send it to next activity through 'putExtra'

On next activity what i am doing is

```
        String item;
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        if (extras != null) {
            item = extras.getString("item");
        }
```

Now lets say here **item = "Java";**

Now what I want is 
        **termsArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Java);**

But i donot want R.array.Java, I want some thing like R.array.**item**

**String Arrays in XML**

```
<string-array name="Java">
<item>A</item>
<item>B</item>
<item>C</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="C">
<item>A</item>
<item>B</item>
<item>C</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="php">
<item>A</item>
<item>B</item>
<item>C</item>
</string-array>
```

I can do this task using IF-else but I have many String Arrays, so it is not possible to use IF-else

Comment: might this be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/3044081/603744

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try as:

```
 String item;
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        if (extras != null) {
            item = extras.getString("item");
            int arryid = this.getResources().getIdentifier(item, "array",
                this.getPackageName()); 
            termsArray  = this.getResources().getStringArray(arryid);
        }
```