# Loading Image based on String

Tags: java, android, string, image

My ultimate goal is this: I have two spinners, `spinner1, spinner2`, each with their own values. One image, named `image`. There are strings, named `start, end, file`. One button, `button`.

My code looks as such:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    start = sStart.getSelectedItem().toString();
    end = sEnd.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if (start.equals(end)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You cannot end where you start.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        works = false;
    }
    if (works) {
        start = start.replace(" ","_");
        end = end.replace(" ","_");
        file = "@drawable/" + start + end + ".gif";
    }
}
```

The file name matches the contents of `start + end + ".gif"` perfectly, so I would like to set the image to the file name which corresponds to the string's content.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042961/how-can-i-get-the-resource-id-of-an-image-if-i-know-its-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what i've done (more or less, i don't have my code in front of me),
i put my image file in assets, then i create my method around :

```
InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open(filename);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new BufferedInputStream(stream));
```

this reads file from assets and convert this to Bitmap

you coulkd also use context.getResources() but i don't remember what to do next