# android how to get view's ID from name

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i get the resource id of an image if I know its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042961/how-can-i-get-the-resource-id-of-an-image-if-i-know-its-name)

hi i want to get the id of an image,i could do this,

```
int id = R.layout.imagename
```

then i could do this

```
imageView.setImageResource(id)
```

but my question is how to get the id if i know the imagename changes at run time, so on this case how can i make `R.layout."imagename"` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042961/how-can-i-get-the-resource-id-of-an-image-if-i-know-its-name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476430/how-to-get-a-resource-id-with-a-known-ressource-name

Comment: @GeorgyGobozov your comment helps me , would you write it as an answer to accept please, thank you

Comment: this line will help `int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("nameOfDrawable", "drawable", this.getPackageName());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just copied [Francesco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3044081/1134705), I hope you will up vote his answer

```
String mDrawableName = "myappicon";
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
```