# How to put variable value into a code

Tags: java, android

I have two spinners. One of them, for exmaple display stringarray "countries" from strings.xml with values "Russia", "USA" and so on.
Also   i have stringarray  with the name of country, for exmaple stringarray "Russia"  and items in  it "Moscow", "Penza" and so on.

When user select an item in countries i want to put item to a string variable and use it in my code line like R.array.{stringvariablevalue}

```
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinneradapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.{selectedItem value must be here}, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

sorry for my English, and thank You.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042961/how-can-i-get-the-resource-id-of-an-image-if-i-know-its-name ... but at your place I would use the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(countryName, "array", getPackageName());
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinneradapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, id, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```