# How enforce certain order of layout elements ids

Tags: android, android-layout

I have several layout elements which I want to process as an array, for example:

```
  for (int j=0; j< N; j++)
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.groupStart+j)).setText(getRowText(j));
```

The problem is that Android doesn't understand ID definition like

```
   android:id="@+id/groupStart+1"
```

Perhaps I can't find right syntax. I can assure certain IDs for element if I add them in a layout grammatically, but I want to define them in resource. I can't also edit R.java because it is automatically generated. Any recommendations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i get the resource id of an image if I know its name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042961/how-can-i-get-the-resource-id-of-an-image-if-i-know-its-name)

Comment: No duplicate, the question is different

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("groupStart"+i, "id", getPackageName());
    view = findViewById(resID);
}
```

Where ids are:

```
android:id="@+id/groupStart1"
android:id="@+id/groupStart2" 
.
.
.
```