# Null pointer exception on getting drawable from ImageVeiw

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, drawable

I have:
    public class TestButton extends ImageButton {....

I have some code which generates a null pointer exception at:

```
  final Drawable temp1 = babyview.getDrawable();
```

Before this I use:

```
 public void dancebabydance() {
  babyview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.baby);
```

Here is the xml portion:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/baby"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/dbaby2"
     />
```

I am ideally trying to compare this dbaby2 to a drawable and see if they are equal, and if they are change them to something new.

Can this be done extending ImageButton like this? Where am I stuffing up?

Comment: This may be dumb, but are you setting contentView to whatever layout your ImageView is a a part of?

Comment: from where you are calling `dancebabydance()`? post that part also

Comment: as mentioned in my answer use `android:tag` to set a `String` and use that to compare your images... you can set the resource id as the tag value or set the resource name...

Comment: Yes, I didn't set contentView within this class, that is it I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the second part

```
babyview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.baby);
```

in the class(is it an `Activity`?) view there is no such view. It usually happens because of one of three reasons:

1) you forgot to `setContentView`

2) you try to get view before you called `setContentView`

3) you use a wrong layout in `setContentView`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the `android:tag` field to set a `String` that you can compare. No other method is going to work well for you.

`getDrawable()` will only have a value if you called `setImageDrawable()` in your code.
If you are trying to get the drawable you provided in the `android:src` attribute.. well you have to get it directly from resources you cannot get it from the `ImageView`.

If you know the resource id (R.id.my_drawable for example) and want to get the Drawable you can use:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.my_drawable);
    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageDrawable(d);
```

If you don't know the resource id look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042961/how-can-i-get-the-resource-id-of-an-image-if-i-know-its-name).

You can get the a `Bitmap` of the `ImageView` however.
You can call `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` then call `getDrawaingCache()` to get a `Bitmap`. If you do this remember to set `setDrawingCacheEnabled(false)`.