# how can i use String variable instead of using R.id.webview1 in android

Tags: java, android

Such as:

```
String ResId="R."+"id."+"webview1";
```

Then use ResId as argument of findViewById method like-

```
WebView webv= (WebView)findViewById(ResId);
```

Please make an answer for me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i get the resource id of an image if I know its name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042961/how-can-i-get-the-resource-id-of-an-image-if-i-know-its-name)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `Resources.getIdentifier()`. In your case, it would be like so:

```
String ResId = "webview1";
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(ResId, "id", getPackageName());
WebView webv = (WebView) findViewById(id);
```

You need to do it this way, as `findViewById()` will only take an `int` parameter.

Should you need to do the same for different types of resources, e.g., a layout, drawable, etc., you would substitute the corresponding String for the second parameter. That is, "layout", "drawable", etc.

Comment: bro when i invoke getidentifier method as above then my app closes unfortunately but does not show error

Comment: Check your logcat. I make a habit of running all (well, most) of the code I post, and this worked for me as expected. I'll double check.

Comment: i checked logcat it shows W InputMethodManager message

Comment: What does it show exactly? What's the error?

Comment: Well! I totally stuck my foot in my mouth with that "always test my code" remark! I accidentally left the "R." + "id." in the String ResId line when I copied your post to my answer. It's been fixed. This should have nothing to do with your current error, however, @user3026481.

Answer (score 0):

R.id.webView1 is an integer not an String just change this to:

```
int ResId = R.id.webview1;
```

give me feedback if it worked ;) happy programming

Comment: bro it shows error indicating java.lang.string cannot be assigned to type int

Comment: @Coderji, I think you meant to leave out the parentheses, like so: int ResId = R.id.webview1.

Comment: @user3026481, take out the parentheses.

Comment: sorry i edited it, @Mike was 100% right. thanks fir reminding me.

Comment: @user3026481 hope it works now. inform me

Comment: bro i want to code "R."+"id."+"webview1" separately and wanna make them as argument of findViewById method. How can i code this...

Comment: Coderji, does that actually work?

Comment: @mttdrb you are right, i though theoretically it will work, but after trying it it didnt.

Comment: this doesn't answer his question. He wants to create a String

Comment: @mikeyaworski that was the answer of his first question, check the edited part of his question first!

Comment: bro ParseInt does not show errors but in runtime my activity does not load

Comment: @user3026481 unfortunately the method I gave it to you is wrong I thought theoretically it will work but after trying it, it didnt work

Comment: So if there is another way please let me know