# Image Resource Gives 0 in Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing a small online shopping application in Android which needs to have lot of items images, I have a web service which gives the path of image present in android drawable-mdpi, My problem here that I tried this code to get the imageresource id, but it always gives me 0.

```
String uri = "@drawable/bangle1.png";
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());
```

Is there any method, to get resource id, so that I can use it for drawable like :

```
Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
```

I tried googling but most of them suggested the above method and this gives me always 0 value. Any one please help here.

Comment: If it is already in the drawables folder, why not use `int imageResource = R.drawable.bangle1;`?

Comment: @dcharms i need to get the response from webservice , that which image to be displayed on activity list view. thats why i am trying it.

Comment: I see. Sorry I misunderstood how you were determining the drawable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all , even i tried it all suggested answers by others , it didnt resolve but i found finally the solution here: [How do I get the resource id of an image if I know its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042961/how-can-i-get-the-resource-id-of-an-image-if-i-know-its-name).

it worked magically:

```
String mDrawableName = "bangle1";
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Here , myDrawableName should not have extension like : ".png". Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to get your images into /assets/ folder, and don't use drawable resources for that. Because `Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.`

If you still want to use your method try 
`getResources().getIdentifier("bangle1.png", "drawable", getPackageName());`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're writing the image name with its suffix. Try using this code:

```
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(
    "your image name without suffix(bangle1)", "drawable", YourActivtyName.this);
```

Comment: i have answered my question, here below before itself, pls see that. Any other way to get image Resource id will be accepted.