# How to convert String to Integer for Icon Resource?

Tags: android, android-resources

the icon name is : icon1.png

```
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon1)));
```

I want to use the String **icon_name**
the String **icon_name** will be updated from server, but all the icons are in drawable. I just change the name, and the code should search in folder drawable.

That means, it should like that :

```
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(xxxxx icon_name)));
```

I have tried like that :

```
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(Integer.parseInt("R.drawable."+icon_name))));
```

android-studio accepts the format but it does not understand it as path.

how can I implement this to make to icon-name variable and not fixed?

I just want to change the Icon from Server from time to time.

Comment: So you just want to change the name of the image(icon1, icon2, etc..) not the path?

Comment: yes, only the name, not the path. I found at least a methode as solution for this case here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042961/how-do-i-get-the-resource-id-of-an-image-if-i-know-its-name)  it works

Comment: `getResources().getIdentifier(icon_name, "drawable", getPackageName());`