# Xamarin get ResourceId by image

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a collection with a few images, but now I need to find the right ResourceId by the correct Image. How can I do that, because I couldn't find it on internet?

Here is the code where it should be placed:

```
var image = (Image)e.NewItems[e.NewItems.Count - 1];
string resourceID = ....
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have a list of images and you want to know which image is this?

Comment: I want the Resource Id of that image

Comment: you either need to maintain a parallel set of data that includes the id you need, or you could attempt to stuff the ID in an unused property of Image, like StyleID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible as far as I know, to get or set the resource id like so

Assuming you are using a list of Image objects in NewItems.

Maybe you get it if you know the Image name like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042961/how-do-i-get-the-resource-id-of-an-image-if-i-know-its-name)

What are you trying to achieve here? add more information to clarify a bit more

PS: answering cause I can't comment yet

**UPDATED :**

Check the "Loading a Bitmap Resource" section in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/bitmaps)

Comment: I want to draw the bitmap in skiasharp, but I need the ResourceId for that

Comment: Check the "Loading a Bitmap Resource" section in the docs here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/bitmaps

Comment: My stream is null?

Comment: should be because of the source ID
string resourceID = "SkiaSharpFormsDemos.Media.monkey.png";
must be set to where you saved your bit map
I see you accepted this answer, thx and I hope you have solved it

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom image file ,which inherits `Image` and Add unique Id into it.

```
public class CustomImage: Image{
    public int UniqueId {get;set;} = CreateUniqueID(); //Add some logic to create unique id;
}
```

Now,you can use this CustomImage anywhere with unique Id.

you can access it by: `CustomImage.UniqueId`

Comment: And how can I find the Resource.Id then?

Comment: Is UniqueId the ResourceId?

Comment: No, these are different . But UniqueId will serve your purpose. 
Let me know,you just need a unique ID associated Image ? it doesn't matter whether it is a resourceId or some random Integers ?